# Difference in time stamps via puppetdb query and mysql query

Tags: postgresql, puppetdb

I store reports from nodes in puppetdb. I want to check time when reports received from specific node via the following query:

```
curl -sk http://pdb:8080/v3/reports --data-urlencode 'query=["=", "certname", "host.mydomain.com"]' | grep "receive-time"
```

i get the following output:

```
"receive-time" : "2015-12-05T11:57:13.882Z",
"receive-time" : "2015-12-05T11:46:26.826Z",
"receive-time" : "2015-12-05T11:17:15.702Z",
"receive-time" : "2015-12-05T13:13:56.060Z",
```

So i can conclude that i have 4 reports  from 09:32:15 until 11:32:13. and this is wrong ( offset of 2 hours )

At other hand when i query postgresdb backend directly via

```
select certname,puppet_version,start_time, status_id from reports where certname = 'host.mydomain.com' order by start_time desc; i get different times:

 host.mydomain.com | 3.8.1   | 2015-12-05 13:57:07.079+02 |    2
 host.mydomain.com | 3.8.1   | 2015-12-05 13:46:19.658+02 |    2
 host.mydomain.com | 3.8.1   | 2015-12-05 13:17:07.056+02 |    2
 host.mydomain.dom | 3.8.1   | 2015-12-05 13:13:56.608+02 |    2
```

And these are correct times for reports. All settings for server timezone where puppetdb runs are correct. All settings for postgresdb are set to the same timezone.

How can i make query via curl report correct time please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The capital <kbd>Z</kbd> after a time-stamp such as `2015-12-05T11:32:13.718Z` stands for [Zulu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) time, UTC.

The other time stamp `2015-12-05 13:57:07.079+02` with the <kbd>+</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> is the time corrected for your local time zone, two hours ahead of UTC.

So they are both correct in the absolute sense, but you need to add two hours to a time-stamp in UTC to match with your watch.

Comment: Perfect, is there any reason why it returns query results in Zulu time, and not in my local time zone time ?

Comment: When you access the console do you also get time-stamps in UTC or do you get them displayed in local time?

Comment: In postgres console i don`t see any timestamps. I just see there time in correct format which match my timezone exactly

Comment: It might have to do with [this](https://ask.puppetlabs.com/question/18559/puppet-pe-20152-timezone/) and the referenced [support ticket](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/ENTERPRISE-560) where Puppet uses UTC internally and local time conversion is only done in the UI.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will just format output with +2 offset :)
There is very nice 'time' library in python for that

Comment: Don't overlook the correction for daylight savings time...